# Split folder paths in Excel to return the final folder

Tags: microsoft-excel, string, string-manipulation

I have a single column in Excel which has a file and folder path. e.g. C:\1_Folder\2_Folder\3_Folder\my_file.txt

I would like to extract the name of the final folder and place this in a new column. In this example, 3_Folder.

Can this be achieved using a formula rather than VBA?

Edit: the number of nested folders can vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the FIND and MID text functions. This will work for variable number of folders

Path text `C:\1_Folder\2_Folder\3_Folder\my_file.txt`

Find position of next to last slash (B1): `FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))-1))`

Find position of last slash (C1): `FIND("\",A1,B1+1)`

Get the characters between next to last and last slash: `MID(A1,B1+1,(C1-B1)-1)`

Comment: That appears to work with a maximum of three nested folders. In some instances I have 7 nested folders. In these cases these formulas do not work?

Comment: I just wrote this based on your example. I have amended my answer for variable number of folders.

Comment: Thanks for updating your formula. Why are the formulas for cells C1 and D1 referencing C15?

Comment: Typos, fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I use [regex addin](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php) for tasks like this, with regular expression:

`=RegExReplace(A1,".*\\([^\\]*)\\[^\\]*","$1")` - this extracts the substring before the last `\` (practically the last folder as you need)

[image]

Comment: That's pretty slick. Would be nice if Excel supported regular expressions natively.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the accepted answer to [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617349/excel-last-character-string-match-in-a-string).

If you want it in one formula, you can use:

```
=RIGHT(A6,LEN(A6)+1-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE("\"&A6,"\","@",(LEN(A6)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE("\"&A6,"\",""))+1))))
```

... which basically calculates the number of backslashes by removing them all and comparing lengths.  It uses that number to substitutes the last occurrence with a "@" and then turns back around and finds the position of the "@" which it feeds into the RIGHT formula to grab the substring trailing the last backslash.  An extra backslash and a "+1" are added in to handle the case of zero backslashes in the source.  If there are no backslashes, the original string is returned.

If your data already contains "@" then you will need to pick a different substitution character.